# Powershell Script to output all Distribution groups and nested groups into a csv

Tags: powershell

Hi I'm pretty new to powershell so I might be going about this completely wrong but I have to dump all our companies Distribution groups, their nested groups, and the users of those groups into a csv or txt file. So far I got a list of all the names of our Distribution groups by doing

```
Get-DistributionGroup | select name >> goups.csv
```

and from there I'm trying to run it through a script that will trim the whitespace on the names and pipe each value through the Get-QADGroupMember command and output that into a final csv. Here's what I have so far...

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Add-PSSnapin quest.activeroles.admanagement

$GroupList = Import-Csv groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
$_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$_.Name = $_.Name.Trim()}
}

ForEach ($_ in $GroupList){
   $_.Name

 Get-QADGroupMember $_.Name -indirect | sort name >> $_.Name.csv

   }
```

and right now it's saying that "Name" is a read only property. I've tried setting read only as false through powershell but its still giving the same error. Is there something I did wrong when writing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to have been trapped by property [inception](http://inception.davepedu.com/)

The `$_.PSObject` reference gives you access to runtime metadata about the object in question, no need to fiddle around with this

```
$GroupList = Import-Csv groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
$_.PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {$_.Name = $_.Name.Trim()}
}                                           ^
                                            |
                  This is the Name property of the Name NoteProperty from the CSV
```

For the `Name` property that *you* want, you only need a single ForEach-Object run. Also, since the value of the `Name` property is the only thing you are really interested in, you can either just drop `$_.Name.Trim()` in the pipeline instead of assigning it to `$_.Name` or you can use `Select-Object`:

```
$GroupList = Import-Csv .\groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name.Trim()
}

$GroupList = Import-Csv .\groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name = $_.Name.Trim()
} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

You can do with the `Active-Directory` module alone, using the `-Recursive` switch, which serves the same purpose as ActiveRoles' `-Indirect`.
Instead of using classical cmd output redirection, you should pipe the output to `Out-File` or `Export-Csv`:

```
foreach($Group in $GroupList)
{
    Get-ADGroupMember $Group -Recursive | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name | Out-File "$Group.csv" -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help I reworked it like you said and changed the it too `code $GroupList = Import-Csv .\groups.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Name.Trim()
} foreach($Group in $GroupList)
{
    Get-ADGroupMember $Group -Recursive | Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name | Out-File "$Group.csv" -Append
}` but now it's trowing an error saying that $Group in the Get-ADGroupMember command is null or empty. Is there something I missed to need to add to define the $Group variable?